# Configure virtual host in Wildly 12

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-11

I want to configure virtual host on Wildly 12. I tried to configure this:

**standalone.xml**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:5.0">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>

                <host name="mypackage" alias="mydomain.biz,www. mydomain.biz" default-web-module="My_site.war">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                    <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                </host>

                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                    <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                </host>

            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            </handlers>
            <filters>
                <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/11"/>
                <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
            </filters>
        </subsystem>
```

**jboss-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
    <virtual-host>mypackage</virtual-host>
</jboss-web>
```

Bu when I open the domain nothing happens. Can you give me some advice how I can configure it?

Comment: Is there any reason why did you choose to use virtual hosts from Wildfly intead of using a web server like Nginx for that? I ask cause I'm facing the same cenario

Comment: Because you app is Java based.